# jQuery/JavaScript possible way to detect if any other keys excluding left or right mouse click is being used

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm fairly new to jQuery/JavaScript and I've been trying to figure out if it's possible to detect if a user on my website is using any other keys excluding right/left mouse click. If anyone has any ideas would be helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Read about keyboard events: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/keyboard-events/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).keydown('keypress', function(e) {
        alert("keyboard is using right now")
});
$(document).mousedown('keypress', function(e) {
    if(e.which==1)
        alert("left is using right now")
        if(e.which==3)
        alert("right is using right now")
        if(e.which==2)
        alert("middle is using right now")
});
```